# Its necessary to Review Facebook app to show Page Post to anyone?

Tags: php, facebook, magento, facebook-graph-api

I have a Magento store, and I am developing a module to post new products to one Facebook page.

I finish the Page Administrator login process.

I also publish the content smoothly THROUGH: 'POST', '/ $ pageid / feed'

The problem is that. The id that Facebook get back trough response work to se the POST. I can see the publication saying that the administrator has posted on the Facebook Page, but the post is not visible on the page even being identified as the administrator of the page.

I tried to submit my application for review, but this is the response I got:

**Page Tab** 
You already have permission to post to self / managed pages based on being an admin of the app. Thank you! 
web 
You already have permission to post to self / managed pages based on being an admin of the app. Thank you! 
*Unapproved*

**publish_actions** 
Page Tab 
Your app does not need the experience Requested permission. Please see That information is available through the public_profile Already field. 
*Unapproved*

**manage_pages**
Page Tab 
Your app does not need the experience Requested permission. Please see That information is available through the public_profile Already field.

what are 'm doing wrong? This is my code for posting:

```
 ![$response = (new FacebookRequest(
                $session, 'POST', '/$pageid/feed', array(
                         'message'       => "text text text',
                         'link'          => $url,
                         'image'         => $imagen
                                                    )
                                ))->execute()->getGraphObject();][1]
```

And, that are the permissions requested to Facebook Page Admin at the login moment

```
$permissions = array(
        'email',
        'user_location',
        'publish_actions', 
        'manage_pages',
        'publish_stream',

          );

         $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($permissions);
```

### EDITED . SOLUTION

I find solution, to post in Facebook page you need to use page token to crete facebooksession.
To retrieve this token you need tu use this code whit a user token.

```
$response = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/$user_id/accounts') )->execute()->getGraphObject();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the Access Token of a specific page you can do:

```
$response = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/$page_id?fields=access_token') )->execute()->getGraphObject();
```

This will return a simple response like the following, so you don't have to search through the list to find the access+token if you have multiple pages you manage:

```
{
  "access_token": "aaabbbcccdddeee", 
  "id": "123456"
}
```